# Installing Windows on Acer Aspire 5741

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install Windows 7 on my laptop using USB as a boot device. After copying the files from USB, when the system reboots for the first time to continue the installation, it starts again from the beginning instead of proceeding with the normal flow. I'm therefore unable to install Windows.

If I remove the USB just before restarting, the system hangs with a blinking cursor on a black screen. The same problem persists even if I try installing from a CD instead.

How can I install Windows 7 successfully in this way?

Comment: You might need to load the Sata driver for your motherboard during the initial setup of W7, or check the bios for a compatibility (ide) mode.

Comment: I have now tried to restore the system to its factory settings by pressing fn+alt+f10 during restart and then choosing to restore the system to its factory settings. It proceeds normally and the progress bar is filled uptil 100%, after that it prompts to restarts the system and then the same thing happens that happened when installing windows from usb/cd. I have tried using the ide mode by setting it in the bios, but then it doesnt allow me to go the recovery options. I cant use fn+alt+f10 if I use ide mode.

Comment: I would test your memory modules and hard drive, rule out a hardware issue.